# SQL Server convert for batting average

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

And thanks in advance for help..

I am writing a very simple stats tracker for my softball team.. I know how to calculate the batting average, but I need 3 decimal places to show in the result field where it only shows one.  for EX:

Need to show

```
BA = 0.500
```

What is currently showing

```
BA = 0.5
```

I messed up when creating the design so I had to convert the values to floats in the query.

```
SELECT _num, _firstName + ' ' + _lastName AS Name, 
      CAST(_Hits AS float) / CAST(_AtBat AS float) AS BA, 
      _RBI, _Triples, _Doubles, _Singles, _HomeRuns, _Scores, 
      _StrikeOuts, _OutAtBase
FROM _PlayerStats 
ORDER BY _num
```

I've also tried the Convert method, doesn't seem to matter if I use Convert or Cast, they practically the same thing anyway from what I've read.

I think I've tried just about everything here I've been researching similar posts for days.

I also tried to format the binding field that I found someone had a similar issue, but this doesn't work either

```
<td>
   <asp:Label ID="BALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BA", "{0:#.000}") %>' />
</td>
```

Any help is very much appreciated thanks.

Comment: you are mixing up presentation with representation. Using a format specifier "{0:#.000}"  is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
SELECT _num, _firstName + ' ' + _lastName AS Name, 
  str(CAST(_Hits AS float) / CAST(_AtBat AS float) ,5,3 ) AS BA, 
  _RBI, _Triples, _Doubles, _Singles, _HomeRuns, _Scores, 
  _StrikeOuts, _OutAtBase
  FROM _PlayerStats ORDER BY _num
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12896)

Comment: Thanks gillyspy! It didn't occur to me to try casting it as string, totally works.